# Window Form Application in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am new to programming. I am using window form in VisualStudio C#.
My problem is after clicking the first button in my Window Form, It opens the browser and go to Url that I want to login and after that when I click the Second button on my Window Form, it doesn't run the second block of codes. I don't get any error message.
Can anyone help me because I am totally a beginner. Thank you so much in advance!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin";    
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        driver.Url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin";

        var email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email"));
        email.SendKeys("-------------");
        var password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Passwd"));
        password.SendKeys("---------");
        password.FindElement(By.Id("signIn"));
```

Comment: Please change your title based on your specific problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: the two asterisks (*) on `**private void button2_Click` are they there is your code or have you added them in this question?

Comment: I imply here, that the code compiles fine, as the author tested his application, so ** was intended to remark the hot spot.

Comment: As a side note, you should put an `@` in front of your URLs. Search for `verbatim string literal` if you like to read more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Thumbs up for all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `button2.Click += button2_Click;` to your Form constructor, right after `InitializeComponent();`. This line adds the event handler `button2_Click` to the event `Button.Click` of `button2`.

Normally, this kind of stuff does the *designer* for you. If you prefer this way, go to the preview page of your Form, then to the property manager, click the lightning "events" and double click your desired event, in this case `Click`. Having this done, the method body for the button2 click event handler will be generated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and information. It works fine now. I am still new to programming and every bit of information is very helpful.